# Visual Studio 2013: Como referenciar project folders no Using

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Eu estou com um problema,eu tenho no mesmo projeto o estoque e o caixa,eu estou fazendo uma tela que te permite escolher entre eles e dependendo do botão que você apertar ele abre um dos dois.

Contudo para evitar confusão o BLL2, DAL2, GUI2 e Modelo2 foram feitos dentro de uma Project Folder chamada Caixa.

A questão é que no código a seguir,eu não consegui identificar como usar o Using para dizer que eu estou usando o GUI2 nesse código. Como ele está dentro de um folder eu não achei comando para tal.

[image: Screenshot do Visual Studio]

Comment: Esses nomes numerados já são feitos para gerar confusão. Na verdade não sei dizer bem onde está o problema, porque não tem informação suficiente na pergunta para identificar. Onde está o `frmPrincipal2`? O problema é nele. Está no `GUI2`?  Este *namespace*  existe nesse projeto? Fez `using GUI2`? Se não existe neste, o projeto onde ele existe está referenciado neste? É o caso de ter essa separação mesmo? Me parece que está gerando mais confusão quando a intenção era diminuir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não adiciona referência à pasta e sim aos projetos. Se a pasta tiver 5 projetos, serão 5 "includes".

Você precisa clicar com o botão em **References**, depois em **Add** e ir na aba **Solution**. Lá vão aparecer todos os projetos da sua solução.

E para usar as classes criadas num projeto externo, é só adicionar o `using` com o nome do namespace que esta classe pertence. Ex.: **`using BLL2.Models.Cliente`**.

Veja abaixo, o projeto **Admin** tem como referência o projeto **Common** que está na mesma *solution*.

[image: Inserir referência ao projeto da solution]

Comment: Muito obrigado jbueno,como sempre meu salvador,vc tem toda razão,eu me esqueci que eu não adicionei eles nas References,foi um erro bobo,obrigado.